# Full outer join not working, got a multi-part identifier could not be bound error

Tags: sql, t-sql, outer-join

I am doing a full outer join of two tables, but received the multi-part identifier could not be bound error. I couldn't figure out why as I have checked everything else.

```
SELECT      A.INTEGRATION_ID,
            A.CURR_STG_NAME,
            B.CURR_STG_NAME
    
FROM        OPTY0430 AS A
FULL OUTER JOIN OPTY0507 AS B
ON OPTY0430.INTEGRATION_ID=OPTY0507.INTEGRATION_ID
```

I can not use inner join or cross join. I have to use full outer join to achieve what I am trying to do

Comment: Do the close voters believe "OPTY0430" is a typo for "A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you declared alias `A` and `B` for tables you need to use those in join your condition instead of actual table names.

```
SELECT      A.INTEGRATION_ID,
            A.CURR_STG_NAME,
            B.CURR_STG_NAME
    
FROM        OPTY0430 AS A
FULL OUTER JOIN OPTY0507 AS B
ON A.INTEGRATION_ID=B.INTEGRATION_ID
```